# Including comments meta box on a plugin page

Tags: plugin-development, admin, metabox

I want to include the 'Comments' meta box (the one usually seen on the post creation page) on my plugin's admin page. Is there a way to do that? I am aware of how you can use `add_meta_box()` to add a custom one, but I want to simply add the comments meta box of a specific post on a particular admin page.

Comment: I think you can't do that... However, you can play with the html tags and the css classes of wp, like `.postbox` etc. to obtain what ou want

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `add_meta_box` to add predefined boxes to different places in the admin, as long as you know the right handles. In the case of the comments meta box you need:

```
add_meta_box('commentsdiv', __('Comments'), 'post_comment_meta_box', $screen, 'normal');
```

Here [`post_comments_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_comment_meta_box/) is the callback function that fills the metabox. I am supposing your plugin is setting a current post, because the callback needs it (it doesn't make sense to display a comments meta box if you don't specify which post the comments must be taken from). [$screen](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/) is the location of your plugin admin page.